# Adding a constant country code at beginning of UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that the user require to enter a phone number into it.

This is how it looks like right now:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // Auto-add hyphen before appending 4rd or 7th digit
    //
    //
    if (range.length == 0 && (range.location == 3 || range.location == 7))
    {
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", textField.text, string];
        return NO;
    }

    // Delete hyphen when deleting its trailing digit
    //
    //
    if (range.length == 1 && (range.location == 4 || range.location == 8))
    {
        range.location--;
        range.length = 2;
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
        return NO;
    }

    //  Prevent crashing undo bug – see note below.
    //
    //
    if (range.length + range.location > textField.text.length)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    //  Limit text field characters
    //
    //
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 12) ? NO : YES;
}
```

After the 3rd digit, I'm adding a hyphen and than again. What I'm trying to achieve here is to add a country code as constant at start of the `UITextField` and that the user will not be able to remove it. Lets say USA country code, then the `UITextField` text will look like that at start `+1-` and then after writing the full number it will look like that: `+1-600-242-252`

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes a starting country code string which includes the hyphen at the end, ex: `self.countryCode = @"+1-";`. The text field should initially contain "+1-".

I've made my answer way more comprehensive than your original intent because it handles many use cases you've overlooked, for example copy and paste operations with multiple characters, inappropriate hyphen deletion, inappropriate hyphen addition, mid-line insertion, etc. It's still not perfect though because your original answer was unspecific in some ways... For example, if you specify that the user should only be able to enter digits, the code can be much cleaner.

The below implementation is described line by line in the comments included throughout.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    // Combine the new text with the old
    NSMutableString *combinedText = [[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string]] mutableCopy];

    // If the user deletes part of the country code or tries
    // to edit it in any way, don't allow it
    if (combinedText.length < self.countryCode.length ||
        ![combinedText hasPrefix:self.countryCode]) {
        return NO;
    }

    //  Limit text field characters to 12
    if (combinedText.length > self.countryCode.length + 12) {
        return NO;
    }

    // If the user tries to add a hyphen where there's supposed
    // to be a hyphen, allow them to do so.
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"-"] &&
        (range.location == self.countryCode.length + 3 ||
        range.location == self.countryCode.length + 7)) {
        return  YES;
    }

    // Remove all the hyphens other than the one directly
    // following the country code        
    [combinedText replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(self.countryCode.length, [combinedText length] - self.countryCode.length)];

    // Auto-add the hyphens before the 4th and 7th digits
    if (combinedText.length > self.countryCode.length + 3)
        [combinedText insertString:@"-" atIndex:self.countryCode.length + 3];
    if (combinedText.length > self.countryCode.length + 7)
        [combinedText insertString:@"-" atIndex:self.countryCode.length + 7];

    // Store the original cursor position
    UITextPosition *pos = [textField selectedTextRange].start;

    // Count up the original number of hyphens
    NSUInteger originalNumberOfHyphens = [[textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count] - 1;
    // Count up the new number of hyphens
    NSUInteger newNumberOfHyphens = [[combinedText componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count] - 1;

    // Create a cursor offset to reflect the difference
    // in the number of hyphens
    float offset = newNumberOfHyphens - originalNumberOfHyphens;

    // Update the text field to contain the combined text
    textField.text = combinedText;

    // Update the cursor position appropriately
    if (string.length > 0) {
        UITextPosition* cursor = [textField positionFromPosition:[textField beginningOfDocument] offset:range.location + range.length + offset + string.length];
        textField.selectedTextRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:cursor toPosition:cursor];
    } else {
        UITextPosition* cursor = [textField positionFromPosition:pos inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionLeft offset:1-offset];
        textField.selectedTextRange = [textField textRangeFromPosition:cursor toPosition:cursor];
    }

    // No need to replace the string since it's already been done
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: @JesseOnolememen I just tested this code again and it works for me.... Could you explain what you mean by "It limits it to only 2 charachets + country code"

Comment: At first, you could only type 2 characters alongside the country code but I managed to figure it ou. I'm using swift so it was just an error in the conversion that caused the probelm. Works perfectley now. @lyndsetscott

Answer (score -1):

To keep a constant at the beginning, you basically want to check if the constant still exist in the proposed text. If it doesn't reject such edits.

You should not try to insert hyphens at specific editing steps. It's better to manipulate the whole string.

E.g.

1. test if string could be valid. i.e. `starts with +1`
2. remove all hyphens you previously added
3. reinsert all hyphens

In code this would look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField.text = @"+1"; // start with a +1 in the textField otherwise we can't change the field at all
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *proposedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if (![proposedText hasPrefix:@"+1"]) {
        // tried to remove the first +1
        return NO;
    }
    NSString *formattedPhoneNumber = [proposedText substringFromIndex:2]; // without +1 prefix
    NSString *unformattedPhoneNumber = [formattedPhoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""]; // without hypens

    // start with the prefix
    NSMutableString *newText = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"+1"];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [unformattedPhoneNumber length]; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            // add a - every 3 characters. add one at the beginning as well
            [newText appendString:@"-"];
        }
        // add each digit from the unformatted phonenumber
        [newText appendString:[unformattedPhoneNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
    }
    textField.text = newText;
    return NO;
}
```

This is still a very naive implementation. It has a couple of problems, for example the cursor will always be at the end because we set `text` of the textField manually. So the user can't easily remove numbers in the middle of the string. Of course there are ways around this. `selectedTextRange` would be the property to use. And you can't really paste phone numbers into the field. And of course the user can't delete a hyphen.

Formatting while the user is typing tends to get complicated quickly because there are so many edge cases. But that should get you started.

Comment: Remember though that the last grouping is 4 numbers in a row... In your current code it'll group those digits incorrectly, ex. +1-675-973-874-2. Also it won't stop at 12 digits since you haven't handled that yet...

Comment: And I believe selectedTextRange is only for UITextViews